# How you say... I feel good after finally getting closure

Tags: translation, idioms

I'm looking for an idiom that describes feeling better after getting closure/some explanation/clarity on a certain issue... whether breaking up with significant other and having a final face-to-face... getting explanation on death of a loved one.. etc.

Any thoughts?

Comment: 松了口气 or 如释重负 or 解脱了

Answer (score 2, accepted):

松了口气=(literally) to get my lung exhausted=to finally relax

如释重负=(literally) just like having uninstalled a heavy burden=to finally relax

Other expressions include

拨开云雾见太阳=拨云见日（short form）=(literally) to wipe away clouds and fog to see the sun=to feel happy after a catastrophe (metaphor or literally)

Answer (score 2):

I got 恍然大悟/善始善终/松了口气/释然/如释重负/大彻大悟/冰释前嫌/释然放怀，无复蔕芥/尘埃落定 etc. in mind. But they don't mean the same.

Comment: Could you please provide short definitions, or at least what the differences are between the terms?

Comment: "But they don't mean the same." How do they differ? This answer would be a lot more helpful if you could provide some insight into their differences.

Comment: I wish you have 现代汉语大词典 or 新华书店的成语词典, you 'll learn more if you do the research by yourselves. If you do it online, for example http://www.zdic.net/c/2/79/125715.htm, this is the explanation of 如释重负， however I suggest use the standard books mentioned, online website is not reliable if you wish learn it seriously.

Answer (score 2):

恍然大悟 <= you understood something finally

善始善终 <= you have a good start and a good end of a non-trivial task

松了口气 <= relief

释然     <= .... um .... also relief .... but written in a literal manner

如释重负 <= get rid of some heavy responsibilities

大彻大悟 <= understood some great big ideas, changing your attitude/thought/life in a good way

冰释前嫌 <= settled a serious misunderstanding or even quarrel

Answer (score 0):

The phrase **了结一桩心事** is quite nice here

了结 can be used to mean closure, like mentioned in the question ("getting explanation on death of a loved one.. etc.").

**Oxford** && **A Chinese-English Dictionary** both define it as:

> 了结一桩心事
>
> take a load off one's mind

a quick baidu search turns up some example usage:

- 退个党真麻烦,不过总算了结一桩心事。
- 了结一桩心事,转眼看见另一桩心事。
- 订单填完,了结一桩心事。

If you really want to emphasize, feeling good after getting some, *closure* this is not a bad way of doing it.